# How to .install plugin in docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, websocket, jmeter, docker-container

I have a linux command to install Jmeter plugin - WebSocket Sampler

I need run this in docker container - my computer is in macos x system

this command are:

```
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2/cmdrunner-2.2
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-manager/1.3/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar -P /path/to/apache-jmeter-5.0/lib/ext/
java -cp /path/to/apache-jmeter-5.0/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
/path/to/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/./PluginsManagerCMD.sh install websocket-samplers
```

Comment: ...put `RUN` at the start of each line and that's a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

For the websocket-samplers plugin, you don't need to install the plugin manager; you could just download http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/luminis/jmeter/jmeter-websocket-samplers/1.2.1/jmeter-websocket-samplers-1.2.1.jar and put it in /path/to/apache-jmeter-5.0/lib/ext/